# Change tap device gateway

Tags: vps, tunneling, gateway, tap, socks5-proxy

I have vps server, install softether on it , softether use tap device name tap_se with
subnet 192.168.24.0/21  netmask 255.255.248.0  broadcast 192.168.31.259,

clients connect with openvpn or l2tp to softether , and softether use local dhcp to assign ip
in subnet 192,168.24.0/21 to them;

i want to socksify outgoin traffic of softether to another server use tun2socks or alternative , and need to change routes table to do this , what must happen must be :
tap_se ==> tun0  ==> eth0

some suggested routes are :

```
# Bypass upstream socks5 server
sudo ip route add SOCKS5_SERVER dev DEFAULT_IFACE metric 10
sudo ip -6 route add SOCKS5_SERVER dev DEFAULT_IFACE metric 10

# Route others
sudo ip route add default dev tun0 metric 20
sudo ip -6 route add default dev tun0 metric 20
```

or :

```
ip route del default
ip route add default via 198.18.0.1 dev tun0 metric 1
ip route add default via 172.17.0.1 dev eth0 metric 10
```

and i create tun0 with these commands :

```
ip tuntap add mode tun dev tun0
ip addr add 198.18.0.1/15 dev tun0
ip link set dev tun0 up
```

but when do this , i lost my connection to server and need to reboot to routes restore to default, what is correct rules to do all outgoing traffic of tap_se goes through tun0 without lost connection to vps